# Wrong action with switch tab shortcut using right ctrl button

Tags: google-chrome

I want to switch tabs with the Ctrl+Page Up/Down shortcuts on Chrome (using the latest version). It always works correctly when I use the left Ctrl button, but with the right Ctrl button, it only works properly on some days. When it doesn't, it becomes page up/down instead of correctly being next/previous tab. I usually browse tabs for the same few sites, so I don't think it's due to the websites. I'm not sure what causes this. Is this supposed to be happening? How can I make the shortcut always work when using right Ctrl?

Edit: Found that it's basically any "ctrl+" shortcuts and not just next/previous tab. Also, I changed my keyboard recently, but this problem has existed since my old keyboard which I've used for 4 or more years, over at least two different computers, and Chrome is the only browser I use so I don't know if this problem will still exist if I switch browsers.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your right ctrl button is not working properly (hardware problem). Maybe it's damaged or somewhat.
2. Some pages maybe does not alove that shortcut's. I'm saying this because i found that on some pages, and my shortcut's doesn't work on them.

I don't see other posible solutions for that.

Comment: For the same sites I usually open in my tabs, I clearly recall some days when I can use the same shortcuts with either ctrl buttons without issue, and other days when the same shortcuts only work with the left ctrl button but not the right. There's never a time when the reverse happens or when both ctrl buttons don't work. This problem is on-off, so it isn't permanent. Also, the problem has existed since my previous keyboard which I used for over 4 years, so I don't think it's a hardware issue.